# Django / Python make newline with '\n'

Tags: python, django

I'm quite new to using Django, so please be gentle, if this is a stupid question.

I'm trying to play with some stock-information in Python/Django. I'm getting the stock-rates from Yahoo Finance (with urllib). Whenever I get some stock-information, then I will get it like this (yep, it's one long string):

```
[b'Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close\n2014-12-01,26.16,26.22,25.85,26.02,48967100,25.54\n2014-11-28,26.80,26.90,26.44,26.49,31185200,26.00\n2014-11-26,26.89,26.97,26.78,26.87,19289700,26.38\n2014-11-25,27.01,27.03,26.84,26.86,28028000,26.37\n']
```

I then send it to a template with Django, using

```
to_be_returned = RequestContext(request, [[DICTIONARY_WITH_VARIABLE]])
```

and then

```
return HttpResponse(template.render(to_be_returned)
```

Is there a way, to get Django to beautify the long string for me? So I don't have to manipulate the string and replace all `\n` with `<br />`, in order for me to be able to read it easier? And what does the [b' ... '] mean (that contains the entire result?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Template filters can be used for this, but what if you want to customize the display? Far better to use `split` and assign each string to fields in a class (or, if you want to cache them, then model fields). Displaying every bit of data right on the template won't help much except when prototyping.

Comment: `b'string'` is how to write a literal for a bytestring in Python (especially newer versions). Each character is one byte wide. This contrasts with the Unicode string, denoted `u'string'`, which represents strings of characters (even wide ones). Python 3 switched the meaning of the unqualified string literal from bytestring to Unicode string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`linebreaksbr`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) template filter:

```
{{ my_string_with_n|linebreaksbr }}
```

`b'...'`  is a python3 [byte string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Comment: Can you also append another method/attribute via `|` in order eliminate the spacing between the lines after the line breaks? I'd imagine something like `{{ my_string_with_n|linebreaksbr|noverticalspace }}`, just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You do not attached a template.
Wrap out tag with

```
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add html tag to the strings that you write in the response

For example :

```
response2.write('</br></br>List of Courses : ')
```